# ember-leaflet - initialize map with zoom to fit all pins

Tags: ember.js, leaflet

I am using `ember-leaflet` with a new project and I've got a component which houses a map with several markers on it called `embedded-map`. I'm following the tutorial on their page and can set a static `zoom` value for my map.

I saw there is some sort of `fitBounds` function available for the leaflet javascript library. Is there a way to access that while using `ember-leaflet`? My documentation search came up short, but I did find a template helper that seems related, but not quite what I'm looking for: https://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-leaflet/docs/helpers/lat-lng-bounds.

embedded-map.js

```
import Component from "@ember/component";
import { computed } from "@ember/object";
import { readOnly } from "@ember/object/computed";

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: "",
  zoom: 10.25, /* I'd like this to initialize to fit all map markers */

  lat: readOnly("trip.averageLatitude"), /* `trip` is a model passed into the component */
  lng: readOnly("trip.averageLongitude"),

  location: computed("trip.averageLatitude", "trip.averageLongitude", function() {
    return [this.get("averageLatitude"), this.get("averageLongitude")];
  }),
});
```

embedded-map.hbs

```
{{#leaflet-map lat=lat lng=lng zoom=zoom as |layers|}}
  {{layers.tile url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"}}

  {{#each trip.days as |day|}}
    {{#each day.dayItems as |item|}}
      {{#layers.marker location=item.coordinates as |marker|}}
        {{#marker.popup}}
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
        {{/marker.popup}}
      {{/layers.marker}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
{{/leaflet-map}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to the problem, thanks to an error message I saw in the console while pursuing @mistahenry's solution above.

The tutorial suggests you pass `lat`, `lng`, and `zoom` parameters into the `leaflet-map` declaration, but the error message states you can also pass in `bounds` instead of the above 3, and wouldn't you know it - it does exactly what I'm trying to do!

I calculate the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude using all of the map markers I have on hand, and pass this into the `embedded-map` component to render the map in a way that will fit all markers on-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not intimately familiar with the latest api, but when I used `ember-leaflet` in a project late 2017/early 2018, I determined at least two options for this use case. Which you choose depends on your use case and what you consider "proper".

You could leverage the `onLoad` action of the `ember-map` component

```
{{#leaflet-map onLoad=(action "showAllPins") }}
```

and handle the bounds setting logic here in the action

```
showAllPins(map){
  let mapTarget = map.target;
  let disableDrag = this.disableDrag;
  // you *can* do totally store the map for later use if you want but... the
  // addon author is trying to help you avoid accessing leaflet functions directly
  this.set('map', mapTarget);

  /* determine min/max lat and lng */

  //set the bounds
  mapTarget.fitBounds([[lowestLatitude, lowestLongitude], [highestLatitude, highestLongitude]]);
}
```

or you can use inheritance by extending `LeafletMap` and have your own custom version of the leaflet map that handles the zoom setting in a domain specific way (extending this class allows you to override/enhance existing methods that have access to the underlying leaflet object).